# Simple proof of the existence of lines in the hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H}^n$ be the hyperbolic space defined as warped product:
$$
g_{\mathbb{H}^n} = dr^2 + \sinh(r)^2 g_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}.
$$
What is the easiest way to show that there exist at least one *line* in $\mathbb{H}$?

A *line* $\gamma$ is a unit speed geodesic $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{H}^n$ such that
$$
dist  \big(\gamma(t_1), \gamma(t_2)\big) = |t_1 - t_2| \qquad \text{for every } t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Can you not do this constructively? Take a line of constant angle through the origin, show that it has zero curvature, and find the appropriate parametrization.

Comment: This is exactly what I have thought. I just wanted to know if there are some faster proof.

Comment: An even faster way might be to show that this model is isometric to one of the standard models, and then use that the geodesics are already known for the standard models.

Comment: I was hoping in the existence of some general result about the existence of lines on negatively curved spaces... :(

Comment: Hint: use that fixed point sets of isometries are totally geodesic.

Comment: @studiosus I can show that a curve of constant angle is geodesic showing that its image coincides with the set of fixed points of a rotation (which is an isometry from $\mathbb{H}^n \to \mathbb{H}^n$). Is that your idea?
But how can I prove that it is a **line** (i.e. that realizes the distance between each couple of its points)?

Comment: @Onil90: In a complete simply connected Riemannian manifold of negative curvature each geodesic is a line.

Comment: Thank you very much! Where can I find a proof of that statement?

Comment: @Onil90: This Cartan-Hadamard theorem, my favorite source is Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of fixed point of an isometry is totally geodesic. Now, if $(S,N)$ are two antipodal points in the unit sphere $S$ there exist an isometry  $\sigma $ of $S$ wich fixes exactly these two points (the restriction of a reflexion to $S$). by the definition of the metric the map $T(r,u)=(r, \sigma(u))$ is an isometry whose fixed point set is $\bf H^1$, i.e. a line. The same argument proves that $\bf H^k$ is totally geodesic in $\bf H^n$ .